# Problemas na busca de dados por nome, não retorna nada

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou com problemas ao fazer a busca de dados por nome. A seguir está o código.
Desde já, agradeço.

```html
<?php include_once 'dbconfig.php'; ?>
<?php include_once 'header3.php'; ?>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="container" style=" background-color:#69C">
    <legend style="color:#FFF" align="center"><h2>Resultado da Busca por Nome</h2></legend>
    <form action="" method="get" id='form-contato' class="form-horizontal col-md-10">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="termo" style="color:#FFFFFF">Pesquisar</label>
        <div class='col-md-7'>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Infome o Nome">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Pesquisar</button>
        <a href='index.php' class="btn btn-primary">Ver Todos</a>
    </form>

 </div><!--container-->

<div class="clearfix"></div><br />

<div class="container">

    <table class='table table-hover table-border table-responsive'>
        <tr bgcolor="#99CCFF">
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Sobrenome</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Telefone</th>
            <th colspan="2" align="center">Ação</th>            
        </tr>
        <?php
            $nome=(isset($_GET['nome']));
            if(!empty($nome))
            {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbpdo.tbl_usuarios WHERE nome LIKE :nome OR email LIKE :email";
                $stm = $DB_con->prepare($sql);
                $stm->bindValue(":nome", $nome);
                $stm->bindValue(":email", $nome);
                $stm->execute();

                if($stm->rowCount()>0)
                {
                    while($row=$stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
                    {
                        ?>
                            <tr>
                            <td><?php print($row['id']); ?></td>
                            <td><?php print($row['nome']); ?></td>
                            <td><?php print($row['sobrenome']); ?></td>
                            <td><?php print($row['email']); ?></td>
                            <td><?php print($row['telefone']); ?></td>
                            <td align="center">
                            <a href="edit-data.php?edit_id=<?php print($row['id']); ?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
                            </td>
                            <td align="center">
                            <a href="delete.php?delete_id=<?php print($row['id']); ?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Não existem dados para visualizar!</td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                }
            }       

        ?>        

    </table>

</div><!--container-->

<?php include_once 'footer.php';?>
```

Comment: Qual o problema? Erro de sintaxe, retorna só uma parte, não retorna nada?

Comment: Não retorna nada.

Comment: Daniel, aproveita e coloca na descrição do seu problema isso que você me disse. Qual o valor de `$nome`? Imprima na tela seu valor

Comment: O valor de $nome, pega-se a partir do método $_GET['nome'].

Comment: Sim, eu sei. Qual o conteúdo? Por isso que pedi para imprimir ela na tela. Talvez como um header `<h1>` para ficar bem grande

Comment: Ok. O valor de $nome é 1, seja qual for o nome que puser na busca.

Comment: Então eu creio que você não tem ninguém com nome 1 ou e-mail 1. E-mails precisam de @, e nome 1 não faz sentido.

Comment: Isso mesmo! E como faço para que o valor de $nome seja o que eu digitar na busca?

Comment: Isso é de `form html` que faz uma vida que não mexo, mal aí. Tente acessar passando o valor no browser, passando o `query param` de jeito controlado: `127.0.0.1/pagina.php?nome=jeff`

Comment: Passando o valor no browser, continua na mesma, até porque mesmo passando o valor na busca, também vê-se o no browser.

Comment: deixei minha resposta, o valor é um porque o isset retornou true! ele não atribuiu o valor do $_GET['nome'] e sim do retorno do isset($_GET['nome']) que é "true ou 1" pois o valor foi passado no $_GET...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá fiz algumas mudanças no seu arquivo, quando você verifica o `isset` e atribui ele a uma variável você está atribuindo um valor booleano (true/false) então acredito que possa ser isso. Outra coisa, quando você usa o `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` você tem que recuperar o mesmo como um objeto e não um vetor. Exemplos:

> Acessando atributo de um objeto:

```
$row->id
```

> Acessando valor de um vetor(array):

```
$row['id']
```

> Nota: Tente também verificar se tá certo a sua conexão com o banco, assumindo que você seleciona um banco default na sua conexão eu tomei a liberdade de remover o nome do banco (dbpdo.) em seu SQL.

Deixo abaixo as modificações que acredito que deveriam ser feitas para o seu script funcionar.

```
<?php include_once 'dbconfig.php'; ?>
<?php include_once 'header3.php'; ?>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="container" style=" background-color:#69C">
    <legend style="color:#FFF" align="center"><h2>Resultado da Busca por Nome</h2></legend>
    <form action="" method="get" id='form-contato' class="form-horizontal col-md-10">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="termo" style="color:#FFFFFF">Pesquisar</label>
        <div class='col-md-7'>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Infome o Nome">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Pesquisar</button>
        <a href='index.php' class="btn btn-primary">Ver Todos</a>
    </form>

 </div><!--container-->

<div class="clearfix"></div><br />

<div class="container">

    <table class='table table-hover table-border table-responsive'>
        <tr bgcolor="#99CCFF">
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Sobrenome</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Telefone</th>
            <th colspan="2" align="center">Ação</th>            
        </tr>
        <?php
            $nome = isset($_GET['nome']) ? $_GET['nome'] : '';
            if(!empty($nome))
            {

                $nome = '%'.$nome.'%';

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_usuarios WHERE nome LIKE :nome OR email LIKE :email";
                $stm = $DB_con->prepare($sql);
                $stm->bindValue(":nome", $nome);
                $stm->bindValue(":email", $nome);
                $stm->execute();

                if($stm->rowCount()>0)
                {
                    while($row=$stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
                    {
                        ?>
                            <tr>
                            <td><?=$row->id?></td>
                            <td><?=$row->nome?></td>
                            <td><?=$row->sobrenome?></td>
                            <td><?=$row->email?></td>
                            <td><?=$row->telefone?></td>
                            <td align="center">
                            <a href="edit-data.php?edit_id=<?=$row->id?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
                            </td>
                            <td align="center">
                            <a href="delete.php?delete_id=<?=$row->id?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Não existem dados para visualizar!</td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                }
            }       

        ?>        

    </table>

</div><!--container-->

<?php include_once 'footer.php';?>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado irmão! Solucionou meu problema.

Comment: @DanieldosSantos Opa estamos aqui pra isso.